# Dropbox content-hash as file fingerprint

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm compiling quite an amount of files in a Dropbox folder and it would be very useful to find any duplicate.

I wonder if it's safe to consider Dropbox `content_hash` property a fingerprint of a file.

Comment: Anecdotally and for practical purposes, yes, but I would verify that two files with identical contents and different names and ctimes are given the same `content_hash`. When I last played with the API that was true, but that was 5 years ago… an eon in technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox API `content_hash` property uniquely identifies the data of a file. You can find more information on it here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-hash

That means:

- Two files with the same `content_hash` should have the exact same
  contents
- Two files with different contents should have different
  `content_hash`s.
- Changing the contents of a file will change its `content_hash`.

(If you instead want to track a file across edits and moves/renames, you should instead use the `id` property. That does not change when the contents changes.)

Comment: [This reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/bausm3/i_need_your_help_to_calculate_hash_file_for/) contains some functional PHP code which you can use as a basis